# how to close app by pressing just Esc. key in C#.Net

Tags: c#

How could i make my Win app that when user press Esc. key and the App. going to close

Comment: Clarification: do you want to get rid of all window decorations (title, border, icon, minimize, maximize, close)?

Comment: please don't change all the question after others answer, you can delete it and answer another one

Answer (score 7):

Edit: Changed my answer since you changed your question :-)

Add a close button to your form and set the `CancelButton` property of your form to that button. Add code to the `Button.Click` event handler that calls the forms `Close` method.

Now you have a button that closes the form and when the user presses escape that button will be clicked.

Comment: @bjh Hans, in this case you should accept this post as an answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

Set `Form.KeyPreview = true` and add an event handler to `Form.KeyDown`. Within this event handler add the following code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @bjh Hans: If you think my answer was good, make an upvote and if you even think my answer solved your problem, mark is as correct. That's the way stackoverflow.com works.